# How to make an array unique by object key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to make an array unique by object key?
I have dynamic checkboxes, whose id I put in the state.

In the format ***[checkBoxId]: e.target.value***

And then I try to make a unique array from the received checked from the checkbox, but nothing comes out

```
[...new Map(
      myCheckboxes.map((item) => { // item {dfsd34534ftg: true} (dfsd34534ftg - id)
      const key = Object.keys(item);
      return [item[key], item];
   }),
).values()]
```

[image]

```
{response.map(({ id}, idx) => (
    <div key={id}>
       <Checkbox
          change={e => {
          setMyCheckboxes(prev => [
              ...prev,
              {
                [id]: e.target.checked,
              },
           ]);
          }}
          checked={myCheckboxes[idx]?.id}
       />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(item)` returns `Array`, which you trying to use as key. You need to extract key from this array in order to make it work as you want:

```
 const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
 return [item[key], item];
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to declare your checkboxes' state

```
const [myCheckboxes, setMyCheckboxes] = useState({}) //define a map
```

And then you can call `setMyCheckboxes` on `change` event like below

```
{response.map(({ id }, idx) => (
    <div key={id}>
       <Checkbox
          change={e => {
          setMyCheckboxes(prev => ({
              ...prev,
              [id]: e.target.checked,
           }));
          }}
          checked={myCheckboxes?.id}
       />
...
```